# APK not compatybile with tablets

Tags: android, apk

I'm trying to publish the app for any device. I assume, that there is something AndroidManifest.xml that causing it to not being available for tablets, but I can't figure out what.

Here is the fragment that could cause troubles:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:xlargeScreens="true"
              android:resizeable="true"
              android:anyDensity="true"/>

    <permission
        android:name="pl.wirtuale.vtk.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="pl.wirtuale.vtk.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

I marked `CALL_PHONE` as not required but still the app is not available for tablets. What else could cause it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is not how you say something is required or not. to not require the telephone you do this

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false"/>
```

also if you want to support everything you dont need to have all this stuff

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
          android:normalScreens="true"
          android:largeScreens="true"
          android:xlargeScreens="true"
          android:resizeable="true"
          android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

you can just delete it, all screen sizes will be compatible. You only use that when you want to exclude certain sizes